# Plot Histogram from csv file

Tags: histogram, opencsv, root-framework

I just started to use ROOT Cern. I have a set of data in a csv file (two columns) which I need to plot in a histogram in root cern. I have found different code but it has been hard to understand, plus it doesn't work when I tried them. Any help is welcome!

Comment: can you post what you have tried to implement / understand so far? It is hard to guess where (reading csv file into root, the class you use, the plotting, running the root cli, doing compilation) your problem lies.

Comment: Yes, thank you for replying. So far I've been doing this that I found in a tutorial:    
void capgam_z025Mn(){
  TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist","histogram", 312,0,7.4);
  fstream file;
  file.open("capgam_z025_55Mn.txt", ios::in);

  double a,b;
  while(1){
    file >> a >> b;
    hist->Fill(a,b);
    if(file.eof()) break;
  }

  file.close();
  hist->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("Energy(MeV)");
  hist->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("Intensity");
  hist->SetLineColor(kRed);
  hist->Draw("HIST");
} This kind of works but it is a txt file. My csv file has two columns which I want to plot as hist

Comment: so if i understand correctly your difficulty is the change in input filename from `txt` (with what content?) to csv. when you say you have two columns that you want to plot, should that be a 2 dimensional **histogram** or the values from one column as a function of the values on the other column? (to be fair, your example looks more like it tries to be a hack that does the latter without histogramming)

Comment: if the columns of your csv file are separated by commas, you might need to call file.ignore() after reading file >> a;

Comment: See also: https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/df014__CSVDataSource_8C.html